# Angular 2 Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target (spec.ts)

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I am building Angular2 App using Angular2 Cli.
I have a notifications.component which has a constructor like this

```
constructor(private _elRef: ElementRef) {}
```

When I build (npm start) I get this error

```
...angular2/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-wKrIZXNv.tmp/0/src/app/notifications/notifications.component.spec.ts (10, 21): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
```

The file notifications.component.spec.ts generated by angular cli is like this

```
import { By }           from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { addProviders, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NotificationsComponent } from './notifications.component';

describe('Component: Notifications', () => {
 it('should create an instance', () => {
 let component = new NotificationsComponent();
 expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });
});
```

However, if I build without the constructor parameter everything works fine. If I add this parameter after building, everything works fine as well.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line `let component = new NotificationsComponent();`.

You didn't provide an argument when you create a new object for `NotificationsComponent` while its constructor expects an object of type `ElementRef`.

That's why you build without the constructor parameter everything works fine.

Comment: I've notice that, but I've tried to provide an argument, but any does not work! What is your suggestion?

Comment: If your `NotificationsComponent` doesn't need `ElementRef`, just remove it from the constructor. Otherwise, you might want to check which test framework are you using and feed a stub to it.

Comment: I could remove, but i would like to know how to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Hi bro well there is a temp fix to this as i am into the same problem and no one yet cannot explain how and for what this is happening but you can try out go into the notification.component.ts and change constructor to: "constructor(private _elRef:any = ElementRef) { }"
reload then change it back to what it was

Comment: Hey mate, tks for sharing this idea! However, it still is getting error.

zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for NotificationsComponent: (?).(…).

I've comment all code inside the notifications.components.spec.ts for the time being!